# How to symbolically find the steady state using sympy's nonlinsolve

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math, solver, economics

I have a standard problem in economics, which I would like to solve using sympy's nonlinsolve.

I want to symbolically find the steady state of a model and to that end solve a nonlinear system of equations.

I was happy to see sympy has nonlinsolve which is supposed to be able to solve such problems but I am so far unable to do so.

In the following you find the part of the problem which does not solve on it's own:

```
    from sympy.solvers.solveset import nonlinsolve
    from sympy import var

    var('c k mc n r_k eta w alpha', Rational = True, positive=True)

    eq1 = -r_k + alpha * mc * k**(-1 + alpha) * n**(1 - alpha)
    eq2 = -w + mc * (1 - alpha) * k**alpha * n**(-alpha)
    eq3 = c**-1 * w - n**eta

    eq_system = [eq1,eq2,eq3]

    nonlinsolve(eq_system , [n,k,w])
```

alpha and eta are parameters whereas the other symbols are variables. I know they are rational positive numbers but for a reason I do not understand yet, the code throws:

**ValueError: alpha: Exponent must be a positive Integer**

Neither do I see why alpha must be an integer nor does it help if I declare alpha as such.

Any hint as to how I can get a meaningful solution using sympy?

Many thanks,

Thore